# Adjust figure margin

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code gives me a plot with significant margins above and below the figure. I don't know how to eliminate the noticeable margins. `subplots_adjust` does not work as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10),range(10))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
```

`tight_layout` eliminates some of the margin, but not all of the margins.

What I wanted is actually setting the aspect ratio to any customized value and eliminating the white space at the same time.

**Update**: as Pierre H. puts it, the key is to change the size of the figure container. So my question is: Could you suggest a way to accommodate the size of the figure to the size of the axes with arbitrary aspect ratio?

In other words, first I create a figure and an axes on it, and then I change the size of the axes (by changing aspect ratio for example), which in general will leave a portion of the figure container empty. At this stage, we need to change the size of the figure accordingly to eliminate the blank space on the figure container.

Comment: try `data = np.random.rand(15,20)`

Comment: You can also use `fig.set_size_inches` to set the aspect of the figure to match the aspect of your data

Comment: If you're just interested in the saved figure, have a look at using `fig.savefig('whatever.ext', bbox_inches='tight')`.

Comment: Using `savefig` with `bbox_inches='tight'` still leaves some padding around the figure. Use `fig.savefig('whatever.ext', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)` to also remove that padding.

Answer (score 90):

I just discovered how to eliminate all margins from my figures. I didn't use `tight_layout()`, instead I used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = plt.subplot(111,aspect = 'equal')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm running in to a weird issue where tight_layout works most of the time, but about 1 in 10 plots just end up being blank with tight_layout. This approach provided me a seemingly more reliable alternative. Thank you!

Comment: This solution also worked for me!! My problem was a really big bottom margin for this scenario: polar plot, `tight_layout()`, `set_theta_zero_location()` with non-zero offset param, along with `set_thetamin()` `set_thetamax()` custom values.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and looks that it is working better than tight_layout()

Answer (score 30):

After plotting your chart you can easily manipulate margins this way:

```
plot_margin = 0.25

x0, x1, y0, y1 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((x0 - plot_margin,
          x1 + plot_margin,
          y0 - plot_margin,
          y1 + plot_margin))
```

This example could be changed to the aspect ratio you want or change the margins as you really want.
In other stacktoverflow posts many questions related to margins could make use of this simpler approach.

Best regards.

Comment: Nuno... so very helpful. Your simple, readable approach is working splendidly for me. I have this little formatter function that works with various x-y graphs that have different extents for both axes, so that I've found that it's necessary for me to write, say, `plot_marginx = 0.05 * (x1-x0)` and to put that before the `plt.axis()` line... likewise of course for y.

Comment: Is this any different than setting xlim and ylim such as by ax.set_xlim()?

Comment: this does same as `plt.set_xlim()` or `set_ylim()`, which is to change the range of displayed data. Which is something very different from changing the size of the axis

Comment: This does not really answer the question as grg rsr mentioned!

Answer (score 22):

`tight_layout(pad=0)` will meet your need.
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout

Comment: figure.set_tight_layout({"pad": .0}) did it for me.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you need is, and it works well for me.

```
plt.axis('tight')
```

This command will automatically scale the axis to fit tightly to the data. Also check the answer of Nuno Aniceto for a customized axis. The documents are in https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis.

Be aware that

```
plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
```

will help remove white space of all the figure including labels, etc, but not the white space inside the axes.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `add_axes` if you want exact control of the figure layout. eg.

```
left = 0.05
bottom = 0.05 
width = 0.9
height = 0.9
ax = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the `subplot_adjust` call is irrelevant here since the adjustment is overridden by `tight_layout`. Anyway, this only change the size of the *axes* inside the figure.

As tcaswell pointed it, you need to change the *size of the figure*. Either at creation (my proposition below) or after, using `fig.set_size_inches`. I'm here creating a figure with a 1:1 aspect ratio using the `figsize=(6,6)` argument (of course 6 inches is an arbitrary choice):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10),range(10))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: I believe you are very close to the answer. Could you suggest a way to accommodate the _size of the figure_ to the _size of the axes_ with arbitrary aspect ratio?

Comment: I see two ways: (1) (the simpler) setting the figure size at creation by guessing the aspect ratio *from the data*. plt.figaspect is a good helper for that.
(2) (more complitated) using ax.get_position() to measure the axes aspect ratio. The latter needs some more computation because the axes position is expressed in a [0,1]x[0,1] relative coordinate space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=1,hspace=0.5,left=0.1,top=0.9,right=0.9,bottom=0.1)
```

And delete the item `bbox_inches='tight'` in `plt.savefig()`.