# Python: bar chart - vertical labels - cut

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am plotting a bar chart (data are stored in a dictionary) with matplotlib in python:

```
plt.bar(range(len(Data)), result3.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(Data)), result3.keys(), rotation='vertical')
```

The problem is, that there is not enough "space" below the diagram so the vertical labels are cut. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You need a combination of adjusting figure size, margins and axis labels font size. There are many ways of adjusting the margins. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619880/matplotlib-adjust-figure-margin)

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for may be the [`tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) function. Try adding the following line to your script:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use figsize? Like here:
`plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))`